# Can't add ppa on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I just installed the ubuntu 15.10, and was trying to installed some apps. But I can't add any repository-ppa. Every time it says "user or team does not exist. ex.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/nemo
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~noobslab/ubuntu/nemo'.
ERROR: '~noobslab' user or team does not exist.
```

Please, suggest a fix for this problem.

Edit: I am not talking about that specific ppa, every time for any ppa it says the same thing...

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~teejee2008/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~teejee2008' user or team does not exist
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~noobslab/ubuntu/themes'.
ERROR: '~noobslab' user or team does not exist.
```

.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: I suffer from the same problem but I have not found any solution for now.

Answer (score 9):

Found the problem for my installation: proxy-server with authentication, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/724224/cant-add-ppa-on-ubuntu-15-10

This leads to this missleading error message. 
But this can also be every error risen during fetching the data. For debugging I altered the file:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py
```

And added a print(e) in the catch case of the function def _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)

Which shows the real reason to me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! For me it was a Proxy issue as well!

Comment: This is also tru if you use the Ubuntu inside a Docker. Changing Docker Network options DNS server to Automatic, or opposite some of the ones from google like 8.8.8.8 solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Turns out that the date on my system was set incorrectly. This shows if I try to manually `wget` the ppa:

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/~ubilinux/+archive/ubuntu/up
--2016-02-11 17:41:18--  https://launchpad.net/~ubilinux/+archive/ubuntu/up
Resolving launchpad.net (launchpad.net)... 91.189.89.223, 91.189.89.222
Connecting to launchpad.net (launchpad.net)|91.189.89.223|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify launchpad.net's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
  Issued certificate not yet valid.
To connect to launchpad.net insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

The date on my system was one year behind. Correcting the date solves the problem.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/679988/how-to-change-ubuntus-server-date-and-time-via-command-line

Comment: I have the same problem, I used the command from another question to update the date `sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the ppa does only work for Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 and 15.04. If you want to download nemo file manager for Ubuntu (do not use this PPA if you're using Linux Mint or if you use Cinnamon in Ubuntu), try the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```

For more info, read [this post](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html).